# Boot Reciever Working on Emulator but not android actual phone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

On boot completed i am starting a service which runs perfectly on emulator but when i run it on android phone Broadcast receiver doesn't start service. Infact app is not even receiving boot completed broadcast from device.

This is my manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver
        android:name="com.darkrai.smsbasedcontroller.BootReciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</application>
```

This is my broadcast reciever class.

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
    Log.d("Boot", "Boot Reciever");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `BroadcastReceiver` -- for any action -- will not receive any broadcasts until something on the device uses an explicit `Intent` to start one of your components. Usually, this comes in the form of the user tapping on an `Activity` of yours in the launcher.

So, add a `LAUNCHER` `Activity`, tap on it, and then you will receive broadcasts until:

- the user force-stops you (typically by means of the Settings app), or
- the user uninstalls your app

Comment: But what if i want my device to start service as soon as its boot is completed. Wt modifications i have to do in above code.

Comment: @user3768061: I already answered that. Add a `LAUNCHER` activity. After the user has launched it, your receiver will work until the user force-stops or uninstalls you. Until the user launches the activity, your receiver will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and its not your code problem or something.
I was facing this problem because of miui. Miui have the autostart permission disabled for every app. 
If you are also using miui device you can do the following option
When you will allow autostart permisson your broadcast receiver will receive the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.
You can allow autostart as
Setting>installed apps>your app> autostart.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices (mostly HTC) has a feature called fast reboot which doesn't trigger `BOOT_COMPLETED`. Instead they trigger `QUICKBOOT_POWERON`.

So add this permission `<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />` also.
i.e.

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.darkrai.smsbasedcontroller.BootReciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```